# Watching Vimeo videos in UIWebView on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, vimeo

I have an app with a UIWebView that I'm trying to view Vimeo videos in. If i hard link it to www.vimeo.com, the vimeo home page and the list of videos loads, however, when clicked only sound plays. If i hop into mobile safari and go to www.vimeo.com, it all looks the same, but the video plays in full screen mode here. I am trying to have my UIWebView act the same way. What am I missing? I have checked this across multiple devices and versions of iOS all with the same results.

Thanks

UPDATE: It actually loads the video BEHIND the view in full screen. Is there any way i can access that full screen video view and bring it to the front?

Heres a bit of code where it's loading. Nothing special though. It's about 3 views in on a navigation controller.

```
urlString =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com"]
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[self webView]setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

**UPDATED FIX**

I found that if i add self.view.window.rootviewcontroller.view as a subview of the existing view before pushing the new view controller, all works great. Thanks, Eric for the help

```
[self.view addSubview:self.view.window.rootViewController.view];
[myNavController pushViewController:urlView animated:YES];
[urlView release];
```

Comment: How did you find out it was loading behind the view? Can you post some code from your controller?

Comment: I can rotate the phone and the status bar moves away and I can see the edge of the video above the nav bar. I think it has something to do with the way the views are laid out, but I'm unsure how to access that view and bring it to the front. Code added to question

Comment: Where are you adding the webview as a subview to your view? You should have something like "viewcontroller.view addSubview: webView" -- do you have any code like that in your controller?

Comment: built through the nib, linked through IB.

Comment: I just added it programatically and end up with the same results, even. I wonder if it has something to do with the way that the Navigation is being handled?

Comment: @iveytron - i am suffering the same issue as yours. I want to know where should i put the code "[self.view addSubview:self.view.window.rootViewController.view];" ? I have no idea  about it. Please help me

Comment: @rohanpanchal, I ended up assigning the navigationcontroller (the first view) to the root view controller with this -`self.view.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and discovered that the fullscreen video is added as a view to the window's rootViewController, which was not the view controller that contained the UIWebView. After setting window.rootViewController the video opened on top of the UIWebView as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, How did you go about changing it in the code?