# Issue in playing vimeo video in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

In my app there is a vimeo video. I have opened it in WebView using following code ;

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/47278503"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        webview.delegate = self;
        [webview loadRequest:req];
```

And place one cancel button above the WebView to close the vimeo video.

But the problem is that audio still plays after closing the WebView by clicking that cancel button.

And another issue is that on viewing full screen, video is not showing ,only audio plays in background and after clicking cancel button the video is playing in background.

**UPDATE :**

There is a similar issue in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085455/watching-vimeo-videos-in-uiwebview-on-ios). I have tried it's code but it doesnt work. I have written the code

`[self.view addSubview:self.view.window.rootViewController.view];`

in tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` method. (and this tableview is in popover).

I have also tried `[self.view addSubview:self.view.window.rootViewController.view];` in WebView's `viewDidLoad()` , but it doesnt work.

What can be the issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for stop BG sound. you just remove, release and set nil to your UIWebView.

Comment: thanks for reply. It works. : ) BG sounds stops. Thanks. But can you please help me to solve full screen video issue?